# UWP GridView Databinding not working with async methods ( observable collection)

Tags: gridview, observablecollection, datatemplate, uwp

Ok I will try to explain my problem step by step along with the code

1. I tried data template with x:bind and observable colection for the first time
2. when i try to get thumbnails of a set of Storage Files and display them along with their display names, it doesnt work.
3. when I just simply add new items to my observable collection with names of those files without getting the thumbnails and putting a simple picture instead of that thumbnail from assets, then it works like it should, but i get asset pic instead of my thumbnail . please help, below is my code ill comment it to explain better. thanks in advance..

   ```
   //this is the xaml code of the gridview.
   <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind VideoGridItems}">
       <GridView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:VideoGridItem">
               <StackPanel>
                   <Image Source="{x:Bind i}" Width="190" Height="130"/>
                   <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" FontSize="24"/>
               </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
       </GridView.ItemTemplate>
   </GridView>
   ```

   //and this is my whole class of the code behind of xaml.cs file

   ```
   public sealed partial class HistoryV : Page
   {
   public HistoryV()
   {
       this.InitializeComponent();
       VideoGridItems = new ObservableCollection<VideoGridItem>();
       LoadHistory();
   }



   public ObservableCollection<VideoGridItem> VideoGridItems { get; set; }
   private async void LoadHistory()
   {
       var files = new List<StorageFile>();
       var TextFile = await Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("VideoHistory.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
       var Lines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(TextFile);
       int i = Lines.Count - 1;
       for (; i>-1; i--)
       {
           files.Add(await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(Lines[i]));
       }
        //I simply take each file and add new items with its name and
        asset picture as image on gridview, this method works, but not what I want
       foreach (var item in files)
       {
           VideoGridItems.Add(new VideoGridItem { Name = item.DisplayName, i = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets//StoreLogo.png")) });
       }
        //below the is code line i have commented because it is not working
        this is the actual method which should work.
       //VideoGridItems = await GetVideoItems(files);
   }
   ```

   }

Finally below is the two classes ive created with a GetVideoItems method in order to get an ObservableCollection which can be bound to the gridview

```
   public class VideoGridItem
{
    public BitmapImage i { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class VideoGridItemManager
{
    public static async Task<ObservableCollection<VideoGridItem>> GetVideoItems(List<StorageFile> files)
    {
        var newlist = new ObservableCollection<VideoGridItem>();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var b = new BitmapImage();
            var thumb =await  GetThumbnail(file);
            if (thumb == null) { b = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets//Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png")); }
            else
            {
                if (thumb.ContentType == "image/bmp")
                {
                    b = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets//Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png"));
                }
                else
                {
                    await b.SetSourceAsync(thumb);
                }
            }
            newlist.Add(new VideoGridItem { Name = file.DisplayName, i=b });
        }
        return newlist;
    }
    private static async Task<StorageItemThumbnail> GetThumbnail(StorageFile file)
    {
        var thumb = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.VideosView, 190, ThumbnailOptions.UseCurrentScale);
        return thumb;
    }
}
```

Comment: x:Bind defaults to OneTime. Have you tried setting the mode to OneWay? Like this: {x:Bind Mode=OneWay}

Comment: i dnt think thts the problem even if it is one time it should still display the result first time, some problem seems to be because of the async and Tasks which I am suing in above methods, i guess how async operates is it executes on another thread and until it gets results the data is already bound. i dnt know much about async and await :/

Comment: Have you tried it with OneWay or not?

Comment: and yes i tried the mode but it gives strange error of object refrence not set to an instance, error is right on the xaml line where i write the mode.

Comment: <Image Source="{x:Bind Mode=OneWay i}" Width="190" Height="130"/>   thts how i tried it and it gives a blue line under mode and says "object instance not set to anything"

Comment: put a breakpoint after this line `newlist.Add(new VideoGridItem { Name = file.DisplayName, i=b });` is i null? might be the problem

Comment: nop i just used this snippet to check what is the problem this snippet works fine and adds one element to the gridview, bit the line I commented thts wht i want to happen, when i place a break point, the Observable collection gets filled but still doesnt show on the screen

Answer (score 3):

Your data template with `x:bind` is right and it can work with async methods. The problem here is related to the `ObservableCollection`. In your code, you used `VideoGridItems = await GetVideoItems(files);` to update your `GridView`, but replacing an `ObservableCollection` like this won't raise any notification, the `GridView` is still bound to the old one. An easy way to fix this problem is using `Add` method to notify the change like following:

```
VideoGridItems.Clear();
foreach (var item in await VideoGridItemManager.GetVideoItems(files))
{
    VideoGridItems.Add(item);
}
```

I used `KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary` as a simple test in my side:

```
private async void LoadHistory()
{
    var files = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFilesAsync();

    VideoGridItems.Clear();
    foreach (var item in await VideoGridItemManager.GetVideoItems(files))
    {
        VideoGridItems.Add(item);
    }
}
```

It works well.

**[Update]**

While using binding, if you want the UI update after data source changed, you need raise a `PropertyChanged` event. If you assign a whole new observable collection to a existing one, this won't raise any `PropertyChanged` event, so your GridView won't update. But if you use 'Add' method, it will raise `PropertyChanged` event. You can find this in `ObservableCollection`'s [soure code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs,767bf62bf4a3a7c1).

```
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        CheckReentrancy();
        base.InsertItem(index, item);

        OnPropertyChanged(CountString);
        OnPropertyChanged(IndexerName);
        OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, index);
    }
```

If you want the UI update after you assign a whole new observable collection to `VideoGridItems`, you can fire a PropertyChanged event to notify the view that the collection has been replaced.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<VideoGridItem> _videoGridItems;

    public ObservableCollection<VideoGridItem> VideoGridItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _videoGridItems;
        }

        set
        {
            _videoGridItems = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("VideoGridItems"));
            }
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        VideoGridItems = new ObservableCollection<VideoGridItem>();
        LoadHistory();
    }
    ...
}
```

And in your XAML, you need use `ItemsSource="{x:Bind VideoGridItems, Mode=OneWay}"` as @gregkalapos said.

Comment: i didnt understand the reason, if i use the add method, and add items one by one, it will work? and if i assign whole observable collection to it it wont work why is that? can u please clarify so that my concepts are clear :)

Comment: @Muhammad Touseef    I've update my answer to clarify it. Hope it helps.